# The 'dart2js' entrypoint script is deprecated, please use 'dart compile js' instead

Tags: flutter, dart, deployment

how to fix this issue ?
normal on local device, but got this issue on the deployment

```
** Building with sound null safety 
Compiling lib/main.dart for the Web...**                          
*Target dart2js failed: Exception: Warning: The 'dart2js' entrypoint script is deprecated, please use 'dart compile js' instead.*
#0      Dart2JSTarget.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/web.dart:246:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      _BuildInstance._invokeInternal (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:847:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:522:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _BuildInstance.invokeTarget (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:785:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:522:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      _BuildInstance.invokeTarget (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:785:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      FlutterBuildSystem.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:614:16)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      buildWeb (package:flutter_tools/src/web/compile.dart:53:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      BuildWebCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_web.dart:135:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1257:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:283:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#17     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
Compiling lib/main.dart for the Web...                            327.4s
**Exception: Failed to compile application for the Web.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables**
```

here's the flutter doctor :

> $ flutter doctor -v
> [!] Flutter (Channel unknown, 3.7.7, on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 5.10.147+, locale en_US.UTF-8)
> ! Flutter version 3.7.7 on channel unknown at /sdks/flutter
> Currently on an unknown channel. Run `flutter channel` to switch to an official channel.
> If that doesn't fix the issue, reinstall Flutter by following instructions at https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install.
> ! Unknown upstream repository.
> Reinstall Flutter by following instructions at https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install.
> • Framework revision 2ad6cd72c0 (3 weeks ago), 2023-03-08 09:41:59 -0800
> • Engine revision 1837b5be5f
> • Dart version 2.19.4
> • DevTools version 2.20.1
> • If those were intentional, you can disregard the above warnings; however it is recommended to use "git" directly to perform update checks and upgrades.
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
> • Android SDK at /opt/android-sdk-linux
> • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.1
> • ANDROID_HOME = /opt/android-sdk-linux
> • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /opt/android-sdk-linux
> • Java binary at: /usr/bin/java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.17+8-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu222.04)
> • All Android licenses accepted.

tried to update the dependencies but still got the same error.

Comment: what is causing "dart2js" to be attempted?  That's deprecated.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz how do i find out ?

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to the stable channel, run commands:
**flutter channel stable

flutter upgrade

flutter pub upgrade

flutter clean

flutter build web**
Hope this helps.